# Is there a way to include individual file names in the master file I make in CMD line?

Tags: command-line

I have thousands of `.prt` files that I'm combining in CMD using:

```
copy /b *.prt newfile.prt
```

I'm importing those into Excel, and it works just fine, other than I would love to include the individual files names as well.

Is there a command I can use for this in CMD? Or something to add to the one I'm using? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The command `for` offers a more flexible way of working with a set of files. The following command will be functionally similar to `copy /b *.prt newfile.prt`:

```
for %i in (.\*.prt) do type %i >> newfile.prt
```

Depending on exactly how you want to include filenames in the new concatenated file, your implementation may be different. Below is merely an example, where the name of every individual file preceeds its contents in the new one:

```
for %i in (.\*.prt) do echo %i >> newfile.prt && type %i >> newfile.prt
```